# Get result HTML from WebPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a System.Web.WebPages.WebPage object I have done some stuff with.
Is there a possibility to get the result HTML from the WebPage?

I have searched at Google, but I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Take a look here](http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/). Taken from this blog:

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) 
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

But if you are trying to do what I think that you are trying (render views into string in order to send them as emails) don't do what I showed, simply use [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) or [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/).

You may also find the [following blog post](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/29/razor-view-engine-without-mvc-at-all/) useful.